# How change icon shown in task bar

Tags: python-3.x

I have this code in this code I have do custom design but when I try to change the icon it is not changing
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from ctypes import windll

```
GWL_EXSTYLE=-20
WS_EX_APPWINDOW=0x00040000
WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW=0x00000080

def set_appwindow(root):
    hwnd = windll.user32.GetParent(root.winfo_id())
    style = windll.user32.GetWindowLongW(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE)
    style = style & ~WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW
    style = style | WS_EX_APPWINDOW
    res = windll.user32.SetWindowLongW(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, style)
    # re-assert the new window style
    root.wm_withdraw()
    root.after(10, lambda: root.wm_deiconify())

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.wm_title("AppWindow Test")
    button = ttk.Button(root, text='Exit', command=lambda: root.destroy())
    button.place(x=10,y=10)
    root.overrideredirect(True)
    root.after(10, lambda: set_appwindow(root))
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the following command to change the window icon

---

```
root.iconbitmap('/path/to/ico/icon.ico')
```

=======

Comment: This is not working properly. If I do this then other function also not working